# How can I capture two columns of ls output in a bash script

Tags: bash, ls

I want to create a script to delete any directories with numeric groups.
What I have so far captures and analyzes the group:

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^[0-9]+$'
for x in `/usr/bin/ls -l /var/indexes | sort -k3,3 | tr -s " " | cut -f3 -d " "`
do
if [[ $x =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "found one $x"
fi
done
```

The problem is, the actual name of the directory is in another column.
Here is one line of the ls output:

```
drwxr-sr-x. 3                     3966 root 4096 Oct 20 16:29 dirname
```

So I need to iterate through the ls results and capture both the group (in this case 3966) and the directory name (in this case dirname) so I can form an rm -rf command to remove it when I find a blank one.
How would I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, parsing ls is bad.  If you have any files without simplistic names you will have serious problems.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to do this in bash, but because you asked, this is how you could split it up.

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^[0-9]+$'
for x in `/usr/bin/ls -l --time-style=+'%s' /var/indexes | sort -k3,3 | awk '{print $3 $7}'`
do
read -A nm <<< "$x"
if [[ ${nm[0]} =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "found one " ${nm[1]}
fi
done
```

It's easier in awk like so:

```
/usr/bin/ls -l --time-style=+'%s' /var/indexes | sort -k3,3 | awk '($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/){print $7}'
```

Really, the right solution is find w/ -nogroup as suggested by Paul H..

Comment: --time-style assumes gnu coreutils. I inferred this because of the date format. This won't work on some unicies like HP-UX.

Comment: I'm all for simplicity but I can't find any info on the -nogroup option on the net ... and the man entry is useless.  I'm interested if you can help.

Comment: [man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) , ctrl-f on the website or / from the shell, type nogroup ? What distribution is this?

Comment: scientific Linux 6.5

Comment: I already looked in the man entry ... all it says is ... No group corresponds to file's numeric group ID. ... which is useless to me

Comment: How is that useless to you?  That sure seems to be like exactly what you are asking in your question.  To find files without a corresponding group.

Comment: "no group" means match if the groupid number does not correspond to any group recognized by the system; viz. it is not in nss or nis and thus ls prints it as a numeric id.

Comment: I tried this ... find * -nogroup ... on the directory and got nothing ... but there is one directory with a numeric group (all the rest have the same group as directory name)

Comment: sorry ... by "useless to me" I'm saying that it doesn't help me to use the command ... the man entry says "no group corresponds to file's numeric group id" which doesn't help me use the command because I don't understand how to use it or what it does based on the man entry.  It's one of those situations where the man entry does not provide enough information.

Comment: `I tried this ... find * -nogroup` - That is the wrong syntax.  find basepath [-options]+.  So try `find . nogroup`.  If you pass a * your shell will glob that, which is almost certainly NOT what you want.

Comment: same result ... nothing returned.

Comment: Thanks Andrew ... I'm using your suggestion above ... insufficient data to try the nogroup thing.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to use find with the -nogroup flag?  For example:

```
find /var/indexes -nogroup
```

If you want to base the script around ls then awk is tool I'd use to select columns.

Comment: Getting the columns to print is not a problem.  Getting the columns into the for loop and the if statement and the rm command is the question.  I don't see any info on the internet on the -nogroup option for find ... and the man entry is useless.

Comment: [man gnu find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) - `-nogroup: No group corresponds to file's numeric group ID.`  The trick with find is to know that there are two fairly common versions, the GNU, and the BSD.  There are lots of differences between the two.